# In yii how to send json in required format

Tags: json, yii, output

I am working in Yii framework. I am having following function-

```
public function actionGetPublicPoll()
{
    $model=new poll();
    $polltype=Poll::model()->findAllByAttributes(array("pollTypeId"=>1));
    foreach ($polltype as $poll)
    {   
        if($poll->isActive==1 && $poll->isPublished==0)
        {
            echo "pollId is=".$poll->pollId;
            $Id=$poll->pollId;
            $option=Polloption::model()->findAllByAttributes(array("pollId"=>$poll->pollId));

            foreach ($option as $option1)
            {
                echo $option1->optionId."</br>";
                echo $option1->option;
                $optionList[]=$option1->option;
            }
        } 
    }
    echo CJSON::encode(array("PollId"=>$Id,"Question"=>$poll->pollQuestion,"options"=>$optionList));
}
```

So i am sending `pollQuestion` and its option in `json` format. From above,I am getting output as-

```
{"PollId":"3","Question":"Which is the biggest district in india ","options":["sachin tendulakar","Yuwraj singh","Rohit sharma","Mahendrasing dhoni"]}
```

But i want json in format:

```
{"PollId":"3","Question":"Which is the biggest district in india ","options":["option":"sachin tendulakar","option":"Yuwraj singh","option":"Rohit sharma","option":"Mahendrasing dhoni"]}
```

So what I need to modify? please help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`$optionList[]=$option1->option`;

to

`$optionList[]=array('option'=>$option1->option);`

................
................

```
foreach ($option as $option1)
{
                echo $option1->optionId."</br>";
                echo $option1->option;
                $optionList[]=array('option'=>$option1->option);
}
```

..............
..............

you will get `JSON` as

```
{"PollId":"3","Question":"Which is the biggest district in india ",
"options":[{"option":"sachin tendulakar"},{"option":"Yuwraj singh"},{"option":"Rohit sharma"},{"option":"Mahendrasing dhoni"}]}
```